# Java logger config file doesn't take effect

Tags: java, file, logging, config

I've got a simple java program:

```
public class UseLog {
    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("UseLog");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        logger.info("my4");
    }
}
```

And a "myConfig.txt" file:

```
.level=WARNING
UseLog.level=WARNING
```

I compile and run it with command line:

```
java UseLog -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myConfig.txt
```

I expected that it should print nothing, but in fact:

```
Jan 05, 2019 10:46:13 下午 UseLog main
INFO: my4
```

So seems that my config file is not effective for my program. Where did I get wrong and how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your config file is ignored because the JVM property is not getting set.

Put the jvm arg before the class name, everything after the main class name is a program argument, not a JVM property.

`java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myConfig.txt UseLog`

If I change your program slightly:

```
package com.soquestion;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Main {
    public static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger("UseLog");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("arg count: " + args.length);
        log.info("hello from info");
        log.warning("hello from warning");
    }
}
```

Output -D after the class name:

```
$ java com.soquestion.Main -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myConfig.txt
arg count: 1
Jan 07, 2019 2:17:17 PM com.soquestion.Main main
INFO: hello from info
Jan 07, 2019 2:17:17 PM com.soquestion.Main main
WARNING: hello from warning
```

Output -D before the class name:

```
$ java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myConfig.txt com.soquestion.Main
arg count: 0
```

Output -D before the class name with a handler defined in the config file:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
UseLog.level = WARNING
```

result:

```
$ java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=myConfig.txt com.soquestion.Main
arg count: 0
Jan 07, 2019 2:18:38 PM com.soquestion.Main main
WARNING: hello from warning
```