# How to remove package name from log line?

Tags: java, java.util.logging

The Java util logging uses the following output line format:

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format = %4$s %2$s %n
```

This gives the following output, where first **main** is a `package` name, while the last **main** is a `method` name:

> INFO main.MySuperPuperClassName main

How to eliminate of the package name here? So that the resulting log line would look like this:

> INFO MySuperPuperClassName main

The idea is to not output the package name in the log line.

Comment: Plesae [edit] your question to include a detailed description on how exactly the logging entry should look like, including the actual message to log. Include example package names, class names and method names. If possible, add a [mcve].

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the definition of your logger. Have you set the name to `"main.MySuperPuperClassName"`, directly or via `MySuperPuperClassName.class.getName()`? Is it an option to change the name?

Comment: If you want to get the name of the class without the package, use `MySuperPuperClassName.class.getSimpleName();`.

For java.util.logging explicitly, there already is an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19783985.

Comment: @Progman if I've got the idea the logget itself was created like `Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MySuperPuperClassName.class.getName());`

Comment: @rozerro The text being logged should be in the format `$LOGLEVEL $CLASSNAMEWITHOUTPACKAGE $METHODNAME $message $NEWLINE`? Specially, the `$LOGGERNAME` shouldn't be used at all?

Comment: @Progman I think the `$LOGGERNAME` comes from thу line I've posted in the previous comment.

Comment: @rozerro This doesn't explain if the logger name should be in the logging output or not. Keep in mind that you have several information like location method name, location class name (without package name), location package name of the class, logger name, logger level, date, etc.. Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description which part of these information should be displayed in the logging output. This can be confusing specially when the logger name is the package name + class name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m pretty sure you cannot do this with logging properties alone.  However, you can write your own Formatter class:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.util.IllegalFormatException;

import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.LogRecord;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;

public class NoPackageFormatter
extends SimpleFormatter {
    private static final String FORMAT_PROPERTY =
        "java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format";

    private static final String DEFAULT_FORMAT = "%4$s %2$s%6$s%n";
    // Java SE's default for US English locale
    //private static final String DEFAULT_FORMAT =
    //    "%1$tb %1$td, %1$tY %1$tl:%1$tM:%1$tS %1$Tp %2$s%n%4$s: %5$s%6$s%n";

    private static final ZoneId ZONE = ZoneId.systemDefault();

    private static String stripPackage(String name) {
        return name.substring(name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    }

    @Override
    public String format(LogRecord record) {
        String formatString = System.getProperty(FORMAT_PROPERTY);
        if (formatString == null) {
            formatString =
                LogManager.getLogManager().getProperty(FORMAT_PROPERTY);
        }
        if (formatString == null) {
            formatString = DEFAULT_FORMAT;
        }

        String name = record.getLoggerName();
        name = stripPackage(name);

        String sourceClass = record.getSourceClassName();
        String sourceMethod = record.getSourceMethodName();
        String source = sourceClass != null && sourceMethod != null ?
            stripPackage(sourceClass) + ' ' + sourceMethod : name;

        String stackTrace = "";
        if (record.getThrown() != null) {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            record.getThrown().printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
            stackTrace = System.lineSeparator() + writer;
        }

        Object[] args = {
            record.getInstant().atZone(ZONE),
            source,
            name,
            record.getLevel().getLocalizedName(),
            formatMessage(record),
            stackTrace
        };

        try {
            return String.format(formatString, args);
        } catch (IllegalFormatException e) {
            return String.format(DEFAULT_FORMAT, args);
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, you can refer to it in logging properties:

```
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter: com.example.NoPackageFormatter
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter:    com.example.NoPackageFormatter
java.util.logging.SocketHandler.formatter:  com.example.NoPackageFormatter
```

Or, you can set it programmatically:

```
private static final Logger logger;

static {
    logger = Logger.getLogger(MyApplication.class.getName());

    Formatter formatter = new NoPackageFormatter();

    for (Logger l = logger; l != null; l = l.getParent()) {
        for (Handler handler : l.getHandlers()) {
            handler.setFormatter(formatter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

## EDIT

changing log declaration to

```
  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(FooBar.class.getSimpleName());
```

and the logging configuration to

```
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s: %3$s %5$s %n
```

gives the exact result expected.

See long answer for examples and context.

---

You can find all documentation needed to proper create a log string here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/SimpleFormatter.html#format(java.util.logging.LogRecord)

Here you get good information about the logging.properties file:
https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/metadata/logging/java_logging.html

from what you're presenting as output, your log config might be being ignored and that's why you don't see results. did you set the property configuration before run the code?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54068185/420096

For example, this java file and this configuration in same folder:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FooBar {

  private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger("my");

  public static void main(String ...args) {
    LOG.info("I was there");
  }
}
```

The file logging.properties:

```
handlers= java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format=%1$tY-%1$tm-%1$td %1$tH:%1$tM:%1$tS %4$s: %3$s %2$s %5$s %n
```

You can test the logging with this command line:

```
java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging.properties FooBar.java
```

And expect an output like this:

```
2024-01-07 08:35:07 INFORMAÇÕES: my FooBar main I was there
```

Where "my" in the output is whatever you use as logger name. Class simple name, for example:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName

Comment: This answer explains how to change the configuration, but the OP already know how to do that.

Comment: @Progman my answer also proposes a solution on how to eliminate the package name, which is the OP question. the extra info added to solve a possible second issue is that bad?

Comment: The package name is not visible because your `FooBar` class is not in a package.

Comment: @Progman my suggestion is to use the logger name, whi i named as "my". The final link points to the getSimpleName method so the OP can either user a raw string or FooBar.class.getSimpleName() Again, there is a solution, a working example, everything OP needs to solve the problem.

Comment: The current answer will still display the package name of the class (if `FooBar` is in a package), but the OP does not want that.